# Why this layout issue?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

You can see in this page: http://www.indiacustomercare.com/blogs/admin there is layout issue for some time but initially it wasn't there.
I've not changed anything in the gardland code.

So in this page #sidebar-right is within #center

If page.tpl.php is being called then #center will occur outside #sidebar-right and I don't have any front*tpl files.

What could be the reason of this?

I'm sure there is no problem with the template files because my localhost version is working fine with same files(including core/template etc) only that little database settings may be different and lacks 4-5 articles compared to this live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have problem with this tag (miss a "div" tag before node list)

```
<div class="clear-block"> 
   <div class="item-list"></div> 
<div id="node-209">...</div>
```

Find and fix it in your page.tpl.php

```
<div class="clear-block"> 
   <div class="item-list"></div>
**</div>**
<div id="node-209">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, there was some crazy thing happening. Yes indeed some plugin was malfunctioning. I've simply removed one line from an article: <img class="company-logo" src="sites/all/themes/ui_garland/logos/airtel.png" style="display:block;margin: auto auto;" width="105" height="38" alt="Airtel customer care logo" /> Now it's working fine! Although this is a perfectly valid html line but in the output page the closing tag of this <img was disappearing! <br> So now I've reset that page to the front page